# Custom Cell TextVIew text not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, custom-cell

I am creating a simple article application in IOS using Swift. I am having issues updating the text inside of my textview.  but I have the textView in a custom TableViewCell class and cannot figure out how to change the text. I have also tried making a setter function. I have no error logs, I am printing the contents of the cell after I create it and after I change the text. When I create it it has place holder text, after i change it it IS changed in the cell in cellforRow, but physically displayed is the text from the xib.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

//mydata
var articles = ["Article","Article","Article","Article","Article","Article","Article"]
var farmers = ["farmer","farmer","farmer","farmer","farmer","farmer","farmer",]
var products = ["coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee","coffee",]
var article = "I am aware that this question has been asked, but none of the answers have worked for me. I'm trying to implement a comments View controller, similar to what you can see in Instagram, where the size of the tableView cell depends on the size of the comment. So I though I would get the necessary height to display the whole comment in textView without scrolling, adjust the textView, then use it to set the heightForRowAtIndexPath appropriately, before finally reloading the table. However, I can't even get to resize the textView, I have tested a certain number of answers and still the textView won't budge."

//flags
var flag = 0 //0=article, 1 = categories, 2 = productpage


// outlets
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

///Default

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let nib1 = UINib(nibName: "Picture2", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Picture2")
    let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "Title", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Title")
    let nib3 = UINib(nibName: "Article", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib3, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Article")



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//TableView

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch flag
    {
    case 0:
        return 3
    case 1:
        return products.count
    case 2:
        return farmers.count
    default:
        return 1
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch flag
    {
    case 0:
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            return 216;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            return 80;
        }
        else
        {
            var hieght = calculateHeightForString(article)
            return hieght
        }
    case 1:
        return 44
    case 2:
        return 216
    default:
        return 216
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch flag
    {
    case 0:
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("View2", sender: self)
    case 1:
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("View2", sender: self)
    case 2:
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Product", sender: self)
        break
    default:
        return self.performSegueWithIdentifier("View2", sender: self)
    }

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch flag
    {
    case 0:
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Picture2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Picture2Cell
            let imageName = "Bag.png"
            let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            cell.Picture.image = image
            return cell
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Title", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TitleCell
            cell.title.text = "THIS IS THE TTITLE"
            cell.by.text = "Zach Chandler"
            cell.country.text = "Camaroon"
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Article", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
            print(cell.textView.text)
            println("Changed")
            let currentText:NSString = article
            cell.textView.text = currentText as String
            print(cell.textView.text)
            return cell
        }
    case 2:
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Picture1Cell
        cell.title.text = "indexpath.section \(indexPath.section)"
        let imageName = "Bag.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        cell.picture.image = image
        cell.subtitle.text = "indexPath.row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = products[indexPath.row]
        let imageName = "bag.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        cell.imageView!.image = image
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text =  "indexpath.row\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "indexpath.row\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell


    }

}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    switch flag
    {
    case 0:
        return 1
    case 1:
        return 1
    case 2:
        return farmers.count
    default:
        return 1
    }
}

//segue

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

}

//personal functions
func calculateHeightForString(inString:String) -> CGFloat
{
    var messageString = inString
    var attributes = [UIFont(): UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)]
    var attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
    var rect:CGRect = attrString!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(300.0,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )
    var requredSize:CGRect = rect
    return requredSize.height  //to include button's in your tableview
}
```

article class

```
import UIKit

class ArticleCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
func SetText(inString: String)
{
    textView.text = inString
}
```

Comment: is your textView outlet connected in your xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the delegate before you change the text, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Should be something like

cell.textView.delegate = self